# See the parent view content while using show(push) segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

In my case, I have a view in the new view controller, I want, when this page would be open, the background of this view has an 50% of alpha. 
Normally, I can use modally present modally kind of segue, then I easily can change the background alpha to see the parent view content. Now, in some reason, I have to do that with show (push) kind of segue and I still need to change the background alpha to see the parent view content.
Is it possible?

Many thanks

here is one screenshot of the views, the background of back one should be clear

[image: screenshot]

Comment: new viewController does have naviagtionController or simple viewController?

Comment: old view hast a navigation bar, so the new one has also a navigation bar. they are connected to each other with a segue

Comment: you can create an another navigationController and set newController as a rootViewController and set alpha of newViewController. it will work for you

Comment: Thanks @SGDev, I just tried it, on that case, there will be no back button

Comment: @matt, no I haven't tried it, can you show me some example?

Comment: @Robert can you add an expected UI screenshot for more clarity.

Comment: dear @SGDev, I added a screenshot in the first post, thanks

Comment: checkout this article:  https://medium.com/@A2HGO/blurred-translucent-ios-navigation-controller-transitions-f38934204f46#.fwggl81td

Comment: Or just override prepareForSegue. Way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this effect using the view controller transitioning api’s introduced in iOS 7 is relatively straight forward.

We‘ll be using the normal UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate methods to specify the animation. Firstly we’ll create an ‘animator’ object which will mimic the standard UINavigationController slide animation.

// UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning code

```
@interface PushPopAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (assign, nonatomic, getter=isPresenting) BOOL presenting;

@end


@implementation PushPopAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.35;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIView *animatingView = self.isPresenting ? toVC.view : fromVC.view;

    CGRect offsetFrame = CGRectOffset(container.frame, CGRectGetWidth(container.frame), 0);
    CGRect finalFrame = self.isPresenting ?  container.frame : offsetFrame;

    if (self.isPresenting) {

        animatingView.frame = offsetFrame;
        [container addSubview:animatingView];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                          delay:0.0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.9
          initialSpringVelocity:2.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         animatingView.frame = finalFrame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        BOOL cancelled = [transitionContext transitionWasCancelled];

        [transitionContext completeTransition:!cancelled];

        if (self.isPresenting && toVC.navigationController) {
            [container insertSubview:fromVC.view belowSubview:toVC.view];

        } else if (fromVC.navigationController && cancelled) {
            [container insertSubview:toVC.view belowSubview:fromVC.view];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

inside your viewController class

```
- (IBAction)pushModal:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self modalController] animated:YES];
}

- (UIViewController *)modalController {
    UIViewController *modal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ModalViewController class])];
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    modal.transitioningDelegate = self;
    return modal;
}


#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                            presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                                sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [self pushPopAnimatorForPresentation:YES];
}

- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [self pushPopAnimatorForPresentation:NO];
}

- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                            animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                         fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                           toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
    return [self pushPopAnimatorForPresentation:operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                         interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController {
    return self.interactionController;
}
```

For reference : https://medium.com/@A2HGO/blurred-translucent-ios-navigation-controller-transitions-f38934204f46#.fwggl81td

Comment: I have put same tutorial as an answer with references link.